# C : Value escapes local scope?

Tags: c, clion

So I have the following toString function:

```
/*
 * Function: toString
 * Description: traduces transaction to a readable format
 * Returns: string representing transaction
 */

 char* toString(Transaction* transaction){
    char transactStr[70];

    char id[10];
    itoa(transaction -> idTransaction,id, 10);
    strcat(transactStr, id);

    strcat(transactStr, "\t");

    char date[15];
    strftime(date,14,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",transaction -> date);
    strcat(transactStr, date);

    strcat(transactStr, "\t");

    char amount[10];
    sprintf(amount,"%g",transaction -> amount);
    strcat(transactStr,"$ ");
    strcat(transactStr, amount);

    return transactStr;
}
```

CLion highlights the return line with a warning: *Value escapes local scope* (referring to transactStr)

I need to know why this is happening (I'm new to C, btw)

Comment: You are returning a (pointer to a ) *local* variable. That can cause (and probably will cause) undefined behaviour, because the value will be "gone" once the function ends. Either use malloc() to allocate the buffer, or change the function to accept a buffer and just fill it. You also didn't initialize the buffer to at least one 0.

Comment: You don't initialize transactStr, so your first strcat() should be a strcpy().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've defined a local variable pointer (edit thanks) inside that function and are trying to return it.

That's a no-no, as the variable's lifetime is only that of it's enclosing scope, here, the function call. Anyone trying to reference the return value will trigger undefined behavior, usually a crash, if you're lucky.

If you want to return the array, you need to pass it in as an argument.

Comment: returning a local variable would be fine, this happens by-value. The problem is returning a *pointer* to a local variable.

Comment: Correct, I'll fix.

Comment: @RonThompson Perfect! I've fixed that issue. But, being that said, once I pass the buffer as an argument, should I return it too? Taking strcpy() as an example, it modifies the values stored in the char[] passed without me receiving it back, as it occupies the same place in memory.

Comment: In that case you can either redefine the function as void or you can use the return value as an error condition if you need to for whatever function you're writing.

Comment: Like in this case if you're unable to convert the transaction to a string you can return a sentinel value that the caller can check for before attempting to process the string.