# "Value escapes local scope" when passing parameters to GSL_function

Tags: c++, gsl, numerical-integration

The problem I have encountered is the following. I am using the GSLs to perform a numerical integration of a function inside a larger C++ program. The code I use to integrate numerically is the following

```
struct psi_params
{
    double d_s;
    double yav_s;
    double sig_s;
    double dE_s;
};

/* Function to define the psi function appearing in the first-passage time formulas. Note that this function holds only
 * for the special potential made by an exponential plus a sigmoid
 */
double psi(double y, void * p)
{
    auto * params = (struct psi_params *) p;
    double d = (params->d_s);
    double yav = (params->yav_s);
    double sig = (params->sig_s);
    double dE = (params->dE_s);
    return pow(M_E, d / pow(M_E, pow(y - yav, 2) / (2. * pow(sig, 2))) - (dE * (1 + (y - yav) / (sig * sqrt(1 + pow(y - yav, 2) / pow(sig, 2))))) / 2.);
}

/* Function to numerically evaluate the integrals of the psi function with the gsl.Note that this function holds only 
 * for the special potential made by an exponential plus a sigmoid
 */
double Integral_I(double d,
                  double yav,
                  double sig,
                  double dE,
                  double a,
                  double b)
{
    struct psi_params parameters = { d, yav, sig, dE };
    gsl_function Psi;
    Psi.function = &psi;
    Psi.params = &parameters;
    double result, error;
    gsl_integration_workspace *w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000);
    gsl_integration_qags(&Psi, a, b, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that my IDE (clion) tells me that the variable &parameters is escaping the local scope in the line

```
Psi.params = &parameters;
```

Actually I do not get why this happen for the following reasons:

1) C++ was never my strong suit and the last time I used it was 7 years ago.

2) The MWE I gave is a minor modification on the example provided by the GLS reference manual ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/integration.html#examples)) in tandem with the definition of a GSL_function with parameters ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Providing-the-function-to-solve.html)). In addition, a MWE similar to the one above is provided by the GSL people [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gsl/2010-07/msg00024.html) to perform numerical integration of functions with parameters. I would expect those kind of examples to be foul-proof.

3) I found an old thread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222061/c-value-escapes-local-scope)) where exiting variable scope is discussed in clion, but I'm not sure if they are related to my problem (see point 1). On top of that, no minimal working example is provided, so I don't understand how to proceed.

Any help to solve this issue is welcome.

Comment: Strongly recommend breaking up `return pow(M_E, d / pow(M_E, pow(y - yav, 2) / (2. * pow(sig, 2))) - (dE * (1 + (y - yav) / (sig * sqrt(1 + pow(y - yav, 2) / pow(sig, 2))))) / 2.);` to make it easier to fir into the human brain. If you ever have to debug it, you'll thank yourself. That said, `pow` is intended to handle really nasty stuff like e to the power of pi. Using it to square numbers is generally overkill.

Comment: I see nothing wrong.

Comment: It seems me a false positive, except that it seems that you need to delete `w` allocation (memory leak)? I guess you need to call: `gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);`

Comment: @Amadeus 's point is good.  Use `gsl_integration_workspace_free` to release the workspace or widen the scope of `w` so you don't have to keep recreating it.

Comment: @user4581301, what you say is correct. The expression is close to unreadable and full of overkill. I obtained it quick and dirty from Mathematica CFormat[] function. I agree that I should update it and make it more readable in next iterations.

Comment: @Amadeus, now I do free the workspace w as you suggested. The "variable escapes local scope" warning is still there, but you state that the code looks fine. 

Do false positive arise often in IDE?

Comment: Sadly yes. In order to keep the IDE responsive they do not, or none I know of, apply the full rigor of a compiler to the code as you are typing, and I haven't seen one take a closer look when the IDE is idle. This probably isn't worth turning off the as-you-type analysis, most of the time it's correct, so you're probably stuck with this one. Addendum: Compiler's not guaranteed to warn you about this if it does happen, so I'd keep this live.

Comment: don't use `pow()` to square numbers.  Just `x*x` is better than calling a function.  Even if the compiler optimises.